# Running a method in the background

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-phone-8, background, windows-phone

I'm developing an app where the app will ask a question to the user, a few actually - for instance asking if the user wants to rate the app. I need to run this method, but it greatly increases the app startup time. How can I run this in the background? I checked other questions on stack overflow without much help. The method that needs to be run in the background:

Called simply like this:

```
checkUserStats();
```

Method:

```
private void checkUserStats()
{
    // Load settings from IsolatedStorage first
    try
    {
        userRemindedOfRating = Convert.ToBoolean(settings["userRemindedOfRating"].ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        userRemindedOfRating = false;
    }

    try
    {
        wantsAndroidApp = Convert.ToBoolean(settings["wantsAndroidApp"].ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        wantsAndroidApp = false;
    }

    //Check if the user has added more 3 notes, if so - remind the user to rate the app
    if (mainListBox.Items.Count.Equals(4))
    {
        //Now check if the user has been reminded before
        if (userRemindedOfRating.Equals(false))
        {
            //Ask the user if he/she wants to rate the app
            var ratePrompt = new MessagePrompt
            {
                Title = "Hi!",
                Message = "I See you've used the app a little now, would u consider doing a review in the store? It helps a lot! Thanks!:)"
            };
            ratePrompt.IsCancelVisible = true;
            ratePrompt.Completed += ratePrompt_Completed;
            ratePrompt.Show();

            //Save the newly edited settings
            try
            {
                settings.Add("userRemindedOfRating", true);
                settings.Save();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }

            //Update the in-memory boolean
            userRemindedOfRating = true;
        }
        else if (userRemindedOfRating.Equals(true))
        {
            // Do nothing
        }
    }
    else
    {
    }

    // Ask the user if he/she would like an android app
    if (wantsAndroidApp.Equals(false))
    {
        // We haven't asked the user yet, ask him/her
        var androidPrompt = new MessagePrompt
        {
            Title = "Question about platforms",
            Message = "Hi! I just wondered if you wanted to have this app for android? If so, please just send me a quick email. If enough people wants it, I'll create it:)"
        };
        androidPrompt.IsCancelVisible = true;
        androidPrompt.Completed += androidPrompt_Completed;
        androidPrompt.Show();

        //Save the newly edited settings
        try
        {
            settings.Add("wantsAndroidApp", true);
            settings.Save();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }

        //Update the in-memory boolean
        wantsAndroidApp = true;
    }
    else if (wantsAndroidApp.Equals(true))
    {
        // We have asked the user already, do nothing
    }
}
```

I tried this now:

Using:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
```

Declaration:

```
BackgroundWorker worker;
```

Initialization:

```
worker = new BackgroundWorker();
worker.DoWork+=worker_DoWork;
```

Method:

```
private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    checkUserStats();
}
```

But it causes a System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Invalid cross-thread access in my app.xaml.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use a background worker thread and put your method call inside it

'The Silverlight BackgroundWorker class provides an easy way to run time-consuming operations on a background thread. The BackgroundWorker class enables you to check the state of the operation and it lets you cancel the operation.
When you use the BackgroundWorker class, you can indicate operation progress, completion, and cancellation in the Silverlight user interface. For example, you can check whether the background operation is completed or canceled and display a message to the user.'

You basically just need to initialize a backgroundworker object and subscribe to its DoWork event.

And the remedy for your exception

```
 private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
      Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
      {   
        checkUserStats();
      });
    }
```

just give a look at this [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) article 
and one [more](http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker) article.